# How does background,text colors affects user's experience in reading?

Tags: color, color-combination

> **Possible Duplicate(s):**
>   [Choosing a set of colors](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/571/choosing-a-set-of-colors)
>   [Is this color readable?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/is-this-color-readable?lq=1)
>   [What is the best color combination for on screen reading?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3282/what-is-the-best-color-combination-for-on-screen-reading?rq=1)

*My QUESTION -*

**How does background and text colors affects User Experience in READING website?**

Does user experience define some sort of algorithms while deciding colors?

*Why am I asking this -*

We are building a product. Which has huge set of links, menus, functionality to do altogether.
I would want users to understand menus & functionality to do in readable & searchable form through eyes.
Users should find easy to -

**Read website**

**Visually search**

**Understand contexts**

Comment: There are already a range of questions in this forum that covers this subject. [THIS](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10742/is-this-color-readable) is one example and I found about three others in addition to that one.

Comment: Yes, this question, and question of it's ilk have been asked in a variety of ways in the past. *Please* use the [SEARCH](http://ux.stackexchange.com/search) feature before asking questions to see if they've already been asked before. This is detailed in the [FAQ].